# Highcharts - xAxis datetime max value does not create a gap

Tags: highcharts

I am currently working on a specific type of chart and I am trying to achieve the following behavior for example :

[image]

As you can see there's a gap between the series last point and the xAxis max value and the reason for this is i wanna have a fix max value and load the daily values of a specific currency as the day passes by. So for example in the morning this chart would be empty and by 18:30 it would be filled.

In my mock example i have the current chart:

[image]

and when I try to set a new xAxis max value ( i also tried softMax) to a future day (using epoch converter for unixtimestamp) i am getting this:

[image]

and i set the max by doing :

```
  return {
    endOnTick: false,
    max:1631962355,
    tickLength: 2,
    gridLineColor: '#b9b9b9',
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    tickColor: '#808080',
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#b9b9b9',
      },
      x: 0,
      y: 12,
      format: '{value:%d.%b}',
    },
    visible: true,
  };
```

}

**UPDATE**
After implementing your response I get an even weirder behavior. I get the same initial start I had before (no difference) but now if i click and drag it to the right I go from this :

[image]

to this:

[image]

and If i click and drag it to the left, into this:

[image]

The transformation happens without animation, neither by wathching the drag and move motion happen. It just instantly transforms after i drag my cursor pointer for a while towards the sides i mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use milliseconds instead of seconds:

```
xAxis: {
  max: 1631962355000,
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/herncjL5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.max

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek thanks for your answer. I updated my question with a new problem that occurred after multiplying my Unix timestamp with 1000 as you mentioned.